# CSS calc() with mulitplication with multiple units

Tags: css, variables, sass, mixins, calc

I have the following mixin in my sass code, to get a responsive-self-resizing font-size:

```
@mixin fluid-text($min-screenwidth, $max-screenwidth, $min-fontsize, $max-fontsize){
    font-size: calc( (#{$min-fontsize}) +
    (#{$max-fontsize} - #{$min-fontsize}) * 
    (100vw - #{$min-screenwidth}) / 
    (#{$max-screenwidth} - #{$min-screenwidth}));
}
```

I defined some variables to keep it clean:

```
//text variables
$min-screenwidth: 480px;
$max-screenwidth: 1260px;
//heading
$min-landingheading-fontsize: 42px;
$max-landingheading-fontsize: 65px;
```

and finally i call this mixin on a h1 headline:

`@include fluid-text($min-screenwidth, $max-screenwidth, $min-landingheading-fontsize, $max-landingheading-fontsize);`

Since I have no syntax error, it wont be appear like i want. I read some articles about calc and some said that calc isn't that improved to calculate that kind of things. I cant believe it, since I got that exact Syntax from a presentation (https://youtu.be/Wb5xDcUNq48?t=1085)

Thank you in advanced for your help and troubles.

***MS***

Comment: you cannot divide by a unit and you cannot multiply 2 units ... it's logical, simply ask your self what does it mean divide by 2px? it's has no meaning ... there is no `1/px` unit ... what doest it mean multiple 2px by 2px? nothing, there no `px²` unit

Comment: read this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Notes. You can obtain what you want if you remove extra units

Answer (score 0):

```
font-size: calc( (#{$min-fontsize}px) + (#{$max-fontsize} - #{$min-fontsize}) * (100vw - #{$min-screenwidth}px) / (#{$max-screenwidth} - #{$min-screenwidth}));

//text variables
$min-screenwidth: 480;
$max-screenwidth: 1260;
//heading
$min-landingheading-fontsize: 42;
$max-landingheading-fontsize: 65;
```

than will do the magic, thanks to everybody!